# What is the best way to fetch RSS, in real time or almost

Tags: rss, real-time, feed, bandwidth

I would like to know what's the best way to fetch RSS feeds in real time without having to download the entire feed even when it hasn't been changed.
I don't really mind the language, I'm just looking for the best way to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `ETag` and `If-Modified-Since` header HTTP header parameters.

Here is a sample python code:

```
etag = ... # etag of previous request
last_modifier = ... # time of last request

req = urllib2.Request(url)
if etag:
    req.add_header("If-None-Match", etag)

if last_modified:
    req.add_header("If-Modified-Since", last_modified)

opener = urllib2.build_opener(NotModifiedHandler())
url_handle = opener.open(req)
headers = url_handle.info()

if hasattr(url_handle, 'code') and url_handle.code == 304:
    # no change happened
else:
    # RSS Feed has changed
```

The code can be transferred to any language where you just add the necessary header tags and check the returned code.

UPDATE: Checkout this blog entry: [HTTP Conditional GET for RSS Hackers](http://fishbowl.pastiche.org/2002/10/21/http_conditional_get_for_rss_hackers/)